# Rubygems does not allow me to install rails 3.2 on ruby 2.0 using RVM

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, rvm, ruby-2.0

I recently upgraded my ruby version to 2.0.0-p0 using RVM. This worked perfectly.
Then I went on to install rails using `gem install rails`. This does not work. In fact, I can't install any gem when using ruby 2.0.0-p0. I tried installing another gem using ruby-1.9.3-p374 and that worked nicely.

This is the error I get when installing rails on ruby-2.0.0-p0:

```
Could not find a valid gem 'rails' (>= 0), here is why:
      Unable to download data from http://rubygems.org/ - too many connection resets (http://production.s3.rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz)
```

What do I do to get Rails working on ruby-2.0.0-p0? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Just give it a time. According to your log, there is something wrong with ruby gems servers

Comment: But this has already been going on for almost a week now.

Comment: i will try install ruby 2.0 and rails, to make sure its not server issue. Untill that, try to simply ping rubygems server for just couple of minutes

Comment: check `gem env remotesources` it should return `https://rubygems.org/` - if it was `http` only then it is your problem, most likely you can configure it in `~/.gemrc` or `/etc/gemrc`